# rspec ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Proposal with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I run test, display error.

Failures:

1) ContractsController POST #create with valid attributes redirects to payment page
     Failure/Error: @proposal = Proposal.find(params[:proposal_id])

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
   Couldn't find Proposal with 'id'=
```

require 'rails_helper'

```
describe ContractsController do
  login_client

  describe 'POST #create' do
    let(:proposal) { create(:proposal) }
    let(:contract) { create(:contract) }

    context 'with valid attributes' do
      it 'redirects to payment page' do
        post :create, contract: attributes_for(:contract)
        expect(response).to redirect_to payment_new_path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

factory girls:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contract do
    sequence(:title) { |n| "translation#{n}" }
    amount 150
    additional_information 'X' * 500
    due_date { 21.days.from_now }

    proposal
    client
    contractor
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :proposal do
    description text
    amount 150

    project
    user
  end
end
```

Comment: Aside the creation of the resource, what else happens in your create action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you're getting this error because of the use of `FactoryGirl#attributes_for`. Why? When you use the `attributes_for` method, it returns a non-persisted hash attribute for the resource. The thing about `attributes_for` however is that it doesn't honor association, which makes sense(in order to keep FactoryGirl ORM agnostic). A suggested way around this is to use or define a custom strategy:

```
build(:contract).attributes
```

[Find more useful references here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/359)